# Derive a State-Space Model for an Electric Circuit with three Energy Storage Components

Tags: capacitance, inductance, kirchhoffs-laws, state-space

I want to model the shown circuit diagram with a state-space model. However, I cant solve it since I obtain four unknown variables while only three of the derived equations are linear independent. Here is how I obtained my equations:

[image: Electric circuit diagram to be modelled.]

The choosen loops are according to the picture below.

[image: Choosen loops.]

All 6 possible Kirchhoff voltage equations (clockwise) are

\begin{align}
V_{C1}-V_{R1}=0 \qquad (1) \\
V_{R2}+V_{C2}-V_0-V_{R0}-V_{C1}-V_L=0 \qquad (2) \\
V_{DC}-V_{C2}-V_{R2}=0 \qquad (3) \\
V_{R2}+V_{C2}-V_0-V_{R0}-V_{R1}-V_L=0 \qquad (4) \\
V_{DC}-V_0-V_{R0}-V_{C1}-V_L=0 \qquad (5) \\
V_{DC}-V_0-V_{R0}-V_{R1}-V_L=0 \qquad (6)
\end{align}

According to graph theory, only three KVL equations are linear independent. Various combinations are possible:

1. Set of independent equations: (1) + (2) + (3)
2. Set of independent equations: (1) + (3) + (4)
3. Set of independent equations: (1) + (3) + (5)
4. Set of independent equations: (1) + (3) + (6)
5. Set of independent equations: (1) + (4) + (6)

The two Kirchhoff’s current equations are

\begin{align}
i_{R1}=-i_L-i_{C2}-i_{C1} \qquad (7) \\
i_{R0}=i_{C1}+i_{R1} \qquad (8)
\end{align}

Inserting (7) in (8) gives

\begin{equation}
i_{R0}=-i_L-i_{C2} \qquad (9)
\end{equation}

The choosen states are

\begin{align}
x_1 = V_{C1} \qquad (10) \\
x_2 = V_{C2} \qquad (11) \\
x_3 = i_{R0} \qquad (12)
\end{align}

The inputs are unnumbered as they are not important for the derivation:

\begin{align}
u_1 = V_0 \\
u_2 = i_L 
\end{align}

The equations for the capacitances are

\begin{align}
i_{C1} = C_1\cdot\dot{V_{C1}} = C_1\cdot\dot{x_1} \qquad (13) \\
i_{C2} = C_2\cdot\dot{V_{C2}} = C_2\cdot\dot{x_2} \qquad (14)
\end{align}

The equation for the inductance is
$$
V_{L} = L\cdot\dot{i_{R0}} = L\cdot\dot{x_3} \qquad (15) \\
$$

Equation (7) together with (13) and (14) becomes
$$
i_{R1} = -i_L - C_2 \cdot \dot{x}_2 - C_1 \cdot \dot{x}_1 \qquad (16)
$$
Equation (9) together with (14) becomes
$$
i_{R0} = -i_L - C_2 \cdot \dot{x}_2 \qquad (17)
$$

By using equations (10)-(17), the KVL equations (1)-(6) can be brought into the following form:

\begin{align}
x_1 + R_1 \cdot i_L + R_1 \cdot C_2 \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_2} + R_1 \cdot C_1 \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_1} = 0 \qquad (1') \\
(R_2 \cdot C_2 + R_0 \cdot C_2) \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_2} + x_2 - V_0 + R_0 \cdot i_L - x_1 - L \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_3} = 0 \qquad (2') \\
\color{red}{V_{\text{DC}}} - x_2 - R_2 \cdot C_2 \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_2} = 0 \qquad (3') \\
(R_1 \cdot C_2 + R_2 \cdot C_2 + R_0 \cdot C_2) \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_2} + x_2 - V_0 + (R_0 + R_1) \cdot i_L + R_1 \cdot C_1 \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_1} - L \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_3} = 0 \qquad (4') \\
\color{red}{V_{\text{DC}}} - V_0 + R_0 \cdot i_L + R_0 \cdot C_2 \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_2} - x_1 - L \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_3} = 0 \qquad (5') \\
\color{red}{V_{\text{DC}}} - V_0 + (R_0 + R_1) \cdot i_L + (R_0 \cdot C_2 + R_1 \cdot C_2) \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_2} + R_1 \cdot C_1 \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_1} - L \cdot \color{red}{\dot{x}_3} = 0 \qquad (6')
\end{align}

The detailed derivation of KVL equations (1')-(6') are further down. They should be correct. My problem is as stated before: I only have three linear independent equations, e.g. (1) + (3) + (5). However, as marked in red, using these 3 equations will result in 4 unknown parameters. Thus, I cannot solve for \$\dot{x_1}\$, \$\dot{x_2}\$ and \$\dot{x_3}\$ without them being a function of \$V_{DC}\$. The voltage \$V_{DC}\$ is the voltage across the ideal current source and results from applying the current \$i_L\$ to the circuit. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Detailed derivation of equations (1')-(6'):

[image: Rearranging of (1)]
[image: Rearranging of (2)]
[image: Rearranging of (3)]
[image: Rearranging of (4)]
[image: Rearranging of (5)]
[image: Rearranging of (6)]

Comment: Did you use a particular criterion to choose the meshes? Which one?

Comment: I did according to graph theory. Here is a video that might be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHkdx70sU5U
Or type "electric circuit linear independent equations loop" in google and you will find a lot of related article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. I was neglecting equation (12). Equating (12) and (17) gives

$$
x_3 = -i_L - C_2 \cdot \dot{x_2}
$$
Solving for \$\dot{x_2}\$ gives
$$
\dot{x_2} = -\frac{1}{C_2}\cdot i_L - \frac{x_3}{C_2}
$$

Thats my missing equation. \$\dot{x_1}\$ is obtained by inserting \$\dot{x_2}\$ in (1'). \$\dot{x_3}\$ is obtained by inserting \$\dot{x_2}\$ in (2').

I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'll present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). Secondly, I assume that the voltage \$\text{V}_0\$ is defined by a voltage source and \$\text{I}_0\$ is defined by a current source. I'll maybe rename resistors, capacitors, inductors, voltages and currents but it will be clear because of the circuit redawn below.

---

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEvwY3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_0-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\displaystyle\text{sL}}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_4-0}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

The Mathematica code to solve these systems of equations is given by:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
R1 =;
R2 =;
R3 =;
C1 =;
C2 =;
L =;
V0 = LaplaceTransform[(*place here the (time dependent) input signal \
of the voltage source*), t, s];
I0 = LaplaceTransform[(*place here the (time dependent) input signal \
of the current source*), t, s]; FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I4, I5 == I2 + I4, I5 == I0 + I3, I1 == I0 + I3, 
   I1 == (V0 - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I4 == (V1 - V2)/(1/(s*C1)),
    I5 == (V2 - V3)/(s*L), I3 == (V3 - V4)/R3, 
   I3 == (V4 - 0)/(1/(s*C2))}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]
```